# Compiler Error Message: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
//......
{
    Product product = new Product();

    product.Name = txtName.Text;
    product.Price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
    product.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
    product.Description = txtDescription.Text;
    product.Image = ddlImage.SelectedValue;

    return product;
}
// ....

 // Line 43:  
 product.Price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
```

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and than [edit] your post with all information to reproduce the problem. I.e. your code probably should be shortened to `int? v = 1.0d;`.

Comment: This means exactly what it says - the Price property is a nullable int, not a double.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like Product.Price is defined as an int rather than a double. We can't know that, though, because we can't see your class Product(). The error is extremely self-explanatory - it is telling you that you are feeding a double value to an int variable somewhere. I'm not one of the smack-down types on this board, but this is a Google question  more than an SO question. IF you still need help, post your Product() class and everthing that gets sent to it.

Comment: I disagree. The question is "why do I get this error" and the answer is "because you're feeding a double value to an int variable." Asked, answered.